# How can i get assocation table colums name? cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am reach this:

```
$this->Users->schema()->columns();//return Users Table Colums Name Array
$this->Users->associations()->keys()//return Users assocation table key
```

But i want to reach associations columns name.

users table: id, user_name, user_password, user_group_id

user_groups: id,group_name

$this->Users->schema()->columns() => return id, user_name, user_password, user_group_id

$this->Users->associations()->keys() => return user_group

i need user_groups table columns name list or array.

Comment: The question is not clear, can you give an example?

Comment: how now? i need association table column name array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the information of any association you can either use the `association()` function:

```
$userGourps = $this->Users->association('UserGroups');
```

Or you can use get it with the magic property by name:

```
$userGroups = $this->Users->UserGroups;
```

After getting the property you can access the schema of that table:

```
$columns = $userGroups->schema()->columns();
```

You can, of course, do it in one chain:

```
$columns = $this->Users->UserGroups->schema()->columns();
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. İ can not think this.